# KnockoutJS with ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: knockout.js, webforms

I am banging my head against a wall here, trying to figure out why I can't get this to work. I have tried following many examples and have stripped everything I have tried down to what I have below.

So, on my aspx page, I have:

`<input type="radio" data-bind="value: individual" />Individual`

Here is my javascript:

```
var serviceBase = 'http://localhost:49906/PopulationSelection.aspx/';
var getSvcUrl = function (method) { return serviceBase + method; };

var ajaxGetJson = function (method, jsonIn, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: getSvcUrl(method),
        type: "GET",
        data: ko.toJSON(jsonIn),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (json) {
            callback(json.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr + ' ' + thrownError);
        }
    });
}

var batchesDataService = {
    getSavedBatches: function (callback) {
        ajaxGetJson("GetBatches", null, callback);
    }
};

var Batch = function (p) {
    this.individual = ko.observable(p.Individual);
    this.household = ko.observable(p.Household);
    this.countOnly = ko.observable(p.CountOnly);
    this.femalePrimary = ko.observable(p.FemalePrimary);
    this.eventManagement = ko.observable(p.EventManagement);
    this.eventManagementText = ko.observable(p.EventManagementText);
    this.randomSampling = ko.observable(p.RandomSampling);
    this.randomSamplingText = ko.observable(p.RandomSamplingText);
    this.stateHasChanged = ko.observable(false);
};

var loadBatchesCallback = function (data) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    myViewModel.Batch = new Batch(parsed);
    //also tried:
    //myViewModel.Batch(new Batch(parsed));
};

var myViewModel;
var viewModel = function () {
    this.Batch = ko.observable();
    this.getBatchInfo = function () {
        batchesDataService.getSavedBatches(loadBatchesCallback);
    };
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    myViewModel = new viewModel();
    myViewModel.getBatchInfo();
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel.Batch);
});
```

I am having no problem getting the data back from my webmethod (using for Session access) and I see the correct info when I alert the Batch members.

My problem comes with the actual `ko.applyBindings()`. No matter what I have tried, I get the following error in the Console:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: individual is not defined;
Bindings value: value: individual
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronicity.

You are calling ko.applyBindings before the ajax callback is getting called, so it doesn't have the value yet.

You may want to call applyBindings somewhere in your callback.

Comment: That did it. I changed the loadBatchesCallback like so:
    `var loadBatchesCallback = function (data) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        myViewModel.Batch = new Batch(parsed);
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel.Batch);
    };`

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I think you want

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel.Batch);
```

Your use of Batch is inconsistent, as well.  You define it in one place as an observable, but then never update it.  I'd recommend following the convention of starting only class definitions with upper case, and instance/property variables with lower case.  This might help clarify what sorts of things you're using where.

Comment: Hrmm...I don't know how it got changed back to viewModel.Batch. I changed it to myViewModel.Batch again with the same results. I'm sorry about that mixup.